# Video filepath stored in database via Room db not working when I try to upload it to server in edit

Tags: android, multipart

> I have stored the video filepath in local database. Then I go to edit
> screen to upload the same stored video to the server but my api is not working with db filepath without selecting the video.
>
> The filepath while selecting the video is:

```
content://com.google.android.apps.photos.contentprovider/-1/2/content%3A%2F%2Fmedia%2Fexternal%2Fvideo%2Fmedia%2F1000019304/ORIGINAL/NONE/video%2Fmp4/1784231912
```

> This is the method I am using to process the raw filepath to send to multipart

```
public static String getVideoPath(Uri uri, Context context)
    {
        try
        {
            final boolean needToCheckUri = Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 19;
            String selection = null;
            String[] selectionArgs = null;
            if (needToCheckUri && DocumentsContract.isDocumentUri(context.getApplicationContext(), uri))
            {
                if (isExternalStorageDocument(uri))
                {
                    final String docId = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(uri);
                    final String[] split = docId.split(":");
                    return Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/" + split[1];
                }
                else if (isDownloadsDocument(uri))
                {
                    final String id = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(uri);
                    uri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(Uri.parse("content://downloads/public_downloads"), Long.valueOf(id));
                }
                else if (isMediaDocument(uri))
                {
                    final String docId = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(uri);
                    final String[] split = docId.split(":");
                    final String type = split[0];
                    if ("image".equals(type))
                    {
                        uri = MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
                    }
                    else if ("video".equals(type))
                    {
                        uri = MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
                    }
                    else if ("audio".equals(type))
                    {
                        uri = MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
                    }
                    selection = "_id=?";
                    selectionArgs = new String[]{ split[1] };
                }
            }
            if ("content".equalsIgnoreCase(uri.getScheme()))
            {
                String[] projection = { MediaStore.Video.Media.DATA };
                Cursor cursor = null;
                try
                {
                    cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(uri, projection, selection, selectionArgs, null);
                    int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Video.Media.DATA);
                    if (cursor.moveToFirst())
                    {
                        return cursor.getString(column_index);
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception e) { }
            }
            else if ("file".equalsIgnoreCase(uri.getScheme()))
            {
                return uri.getPath();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
```

> After processing through above method I get following path to send to
> the multipart:

```
/storage/emulated/0/Download/sample-mp4-file-small.mp4
```

> But it is not working when I fetch the same raw filepath from db and
> process through same above getVideoPath method
>
> **Exception in logcat** soon as I enter the edit screen and try to set the video to video view

Load failed for http://touchpaisa.com/public/content://com.google.android.apps.photos.contentprovider/-1/2/content%3A%2F%2Fmedia%2Fexternal%2Fvideo%2Fmedia%2F1000019960/ORIGINAL/NONE/video%2Fmp4/262855394 with size [489x262]
class com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.GlideException: Failed to load resource
There were 8 root causes:
java.lang.RuntimeException(setDataSourceCallback failed: status = 0x80000000)
java.lang.RuntimeException(setDataSourceCallback failed: status = 0x80000000)
java.lang.RuntimeException(setDataSource failed: status = 0x80000000)
java.lang.RuntimeException(setDataSource failed: status = 0x80000000)
java.lang.RuntimeException(setDataSourceCallback failed: status = 0x80000000)
java.lang.RuntimeException(setDataSourceCallback failed: status = 0x80000000)
java.lang.RuntimeException(setDataSource failed: status = 0x80000000)
java.lang.RuntimeException(setDataSource failed: status = 0x80000000)
call GlideException#logRootCauses(String) for more detail
Cause (1 of 6): class com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.GlideException: Failed LoadPath{DirectByteBuffer->Object->Drawable}, DATA_DISK_CACHE, http://touchpaisa.com/public/content://com.google.android.apps.photos.contentprovider/-1/2/content%3A%2F%2Fmedia%2Fexternal%2Fvideo%2Fmedia%2F1000019960/ORIGINAL/NONE/video%2Fmp4/262855394
There were 2 root causes:
java.lang.RuntimeException(setDataSourceCallback failed: status = 0x80000000)
java.lang.RuntimeException(setDataSourceCallback failed: status = 0x80000000)
call GlideException#logRootCauses(String) for more detail
Cause (1 of 3): class com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.GlideException: Failed DecodePath{DirectByteBuffer->GifDrawable->Drawable}
Cause (2 of 3): class com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.GlideException: Failed DecodePath{DirectByteBuffer->Bitmap->Drawable}
There was 1 root cause:
java.lang.RuntimeException(setDataSourceCallback failed: status = 0x80000000)
call GlideException#logRootCauses(String) for more detail
Cause (1 of 1): class java.lang.RuntimeException: setDataSourceCallback failed: status = 0x80000000
Cause (3 of 3): class com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.GlideException: Failed DecodePath{DirectByteBuffer->BitmapDrawable->Drawable}
There was 1 root cause:
java.lang.RuntimeException(setDataSourceCallback failed: status = 0x80000000)
call GlideException#logRootCauses(String) for more detail
Cause (1 of 1): class java.lang.RuntimeException: setDataSourceCallback failed: status = 0x80000000
Cause (2 of 6): class com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.GlideException: Failed LoadPath{FileInputStream->Object->Drawable}, DATA_DISK_CACHE, http://touchpaisa.com/public/content://com.google.android.apps.photos.contentprovider/-1/2/content%3A%2F%2Fmedia%2Fexternal%2Fvideo%2Fmedia%2F1000019960/ORIGINAL/NONE/video%2Fmp4/262855394
Cause (1 of 3): class com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.GlideException: Failed DecodePath{FileInputStream->GifDrawable->Drawable}
Cause (2 of 3): class com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.GlideException: Failed DecodePath{FileInputStream->Bitmap->Drawable}
Cause (3 of 3): class com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.GlideException: Failed DecodePath{FileInputStream->BitmapDrawable->Drawable}
Cause (3 of 6): class com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.GlideException: Failed LoadPath{ParcelFileDescriptor->Object->Drawable}, DATA_DISK_CACHE, http://touchpaisa.com/public/content://com.google.android.apps.photos.contentprovider/-1/2/content%3A%2F%2Fmedia%2Fexternal%2Fvideo%2Fmedia%2F1000019960/ORIGINAL/NONE/video%2Fmp4/262855394
There were 2 root causes:
java.lang.RuntimeException(setDataSource failed: status = 0x80000000)
java.lang.RuntimeException(setDataSource failed: status = 0x80000000)
call GlideException#logRootCauses(String) for more detail
Cause (1 of 2): class com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.GlideException: Failed DecodePath{ParcelFileDescriptor->Bitmap->Drawable}
There was 1 root cause:
java.lang.RuntimeException(setDataSource failed: status = 0x80000000)
2023-03-20 13:20:05.443  8588-8588  Glide                   com.iloma.salt                       W   call GlideException#logRootCauses(String) for more detail
Cause (1 of 1): class java.lang.RuntimeException: setDataSource failed: status = 0x80000000
Cause (2 of 2): class com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.GlideException: Failed DecodePath{ParcelFileDescriptor->BitmapDrawable->Drawable}
There was 1 root cause:
java.lang.RuntimeException(setDataSource failed: status = 0x80000000)
call GlideException#logRootCauses(String) for more detail
Cause (1 of 1): class java.lang.RuntimeException: setDataSource failed: status = 0x80000000
Cause (4 of 6): class com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.GlideException: Failed LoadPath{DirectByteBuffer->Object->Drawable}, REMOTE, http://touchpaisa.com/public/content://com.google.android.apps.photos.contentprovider/-1/2/content%3A%2F%2Fmedia%2Fexternal%2Fvideo%2Fmedia%2F1000019960/ORIGINAL/NONE/video%2Fmp4/262855394
There were 2 root causes:
java.lang.RuntimeException(setDataSourceCallback failed: status = 0x80000000)
java.lang.RuntimeException(setDataSourceCallback failed: status = 0x80000000)
call GlideException#logRootCauses(String) for more detail
Cause (1 of 3): class com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.GlideException: Failed DecodePath{DirectByteBuffer->GifDrawable->Drawable}
Cause (2 of 3): class com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.GlideException: Failed DecodePath{DirectByteBuffer->Bitmap->Drawable}
There was 1 root cause:
java.lang.RuntimeException(setDataSourceCallback failed: status = 0x80000000)
call GlideException#logRootCauses(String) for more detail
Cause (1 of 1): class java.lang.RuntimeException: setDataSourceCallback failed: status = 0x80000000
Cause (3 of 3): class com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.GlideException: Failed DecodePath{DirectByteBuffer->BitmapDrawable->Drawable}
There was 1 root cause:
java.lang.RuntimeException(setDataSourceCallback failed: status = 0x80000000)
call GlideException#logRootCauses(String) for more detail
Cause (1 of 1): class java.lang.RuntimeException: setDataSourceCallback failed: status = 0x80000000
Cause (5 of 6): class com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.GlideException: Failed LoadPath{FileInputStream->Object->Drawable}, REMOTE, http://touchpaisa.com/public/content://com.google.android.apps.photos.contentprovider/-1/2/content%3A%2F%2Fmedia%2Fexternal%2Fvideo%2Fmedia%2F1000019960/ORIGINAL/NONE/video%2Fmp4/262855394
Cause (1 of 3): class com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.GlideException: Failed DecodePath{FileInputStream->GifDrawable->Drawable}
Cause (2 of 3): class com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.GlideException: Failed DecodePath{FileInputStream->Bitmap->Drawable}
Cause (3 of 3): class com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.GlideException: Failed DecodePath{FileInputStream->BitmapDrawable->Drawable}
Cause (6 of 6): class com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.GlideException: Failed LoadPath{ParcelFileDescriptor->Object->Drawable}, REMOTE, http://touchpaisa.com/public/content://com.google.android.apps.photos.contentprovider/-1/2/content%3A%2F%2Fmedia%2Fexternal%2Fvideo%2Fmedia%2F1000019960/ORIGINAL/NONE/video%2Fmp4/262855394
There were 2 root causes:
java.lang.RuntimeException(setDataSource failed: status = 0x80000000)
java.lang.RuntimeException(setDataSource failed: status = 0x80000000)
call GlideException#logRootCauses(String) for more detail
Cause (1 of 2): class com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.GlideException: Failed DecodePath{ParcelFileDescriptor->Bitmap->Drawable}
There was 1 root cause:
java.lang.RuntimeException(setDataSource failed: status = 0x80000000)
call GlideException#logRootCauses(String) for more detail
Cause (1 of 1): class java.lang.RuntimeException: setDataSource failed: status = 0x80000000
Cause (2 of 2): class com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.GlideException: Failed DecodePath{ParcelFileDescriptor->BitmapDrawable->Drawable}
There was 1 root cause:
java.lang.RuntimeException(setDataSource failed: status = 0x80000000)
call GlideException#logRootCauses(String) for more detail
2023-03-20 13:20:05.443  8588-8588  Glide                   com.iloma.salt                       W       Cause (1 of 1): class java.lang.RuntimeException: setDataSource failed: status = 0x80000000

Any help/ suggestions would be appreciable. Thanks in Advance

Comment: are there any Exception messages in logcat?

Comment: Please act normal. Dont dump all those logcat lines. Ten would be enough.